# Use CTE to generate test data in SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, common-table-expression

I am trying to use a CTE to generate a data table for a unit test in SQL (postgresql).

```
WITH temp1 AS (
SELECT
  ('A', 'A', 'B', 'B') AS grp,
  (1, 2, NULL, 1) AS outcome
)

SELECT * 
FROM temp1
```

The above query is generating a single row rather than a 4-row table that would be useful to my unit test. How can I generate the 4-row table in the form:

```
grp.....outcome
A.......1
A.......2
B.......NULL
B.......1
```

Comment: Use `UNION` inside CTE.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could just use the `values()` syntax to create the rows, like so:

```
with temp1(grp, outcome) as (values ('A', 1), ('A', 2), ('B', null), ('B', 1))
select * from temp1
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=6a5581d0f8cc4549799aa0f71ac10aa5)**:

```
grp | outcome
:-- | ------:
A   |       1
A   |       2
B   |    null
B   |       1
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a CTE. Use `UNION ALL`, as in:

```
select 'A' as grp, 1 as outcome
union all select 'A', 2
union all select 'B', null
union all select 'B', 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH temp1 AS (
SELECT  'A' as grp ,1 as outcome
UNION 
SELECT  'A', 2
UNION
SELECT 'B',NULL
UNION 
SELECT 'B',1
) SELECT * FROM temp1
```